# SFDC LWC -Reactive & Non reactive properties of component are behaving same i.e. both of them are rerendering the values

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have  defined two LWC's one is Reactive & other  is non reactive .So NOn reactive  component should not rerender its values ,But both the LWC's reredenring property values.Let me know what is the issue in my code
Below is my code.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0aaW.png)html code:

```html
<template>
    <table style="background: white;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Reactive Private property
                <lightning-input type="text" onchange={changeHandler1}></lightning-input>
                <br/>
                <b>value: {reactivePrivateProperty}</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
                Non Reactive Private property
                <lightning-input type="text" onchange={changeHandler2}></lightning-input>
                <br/>
                <b>value: {nonReactivePrivateProperty}</b>
           </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</template>
```

[2]JS code:

```js
import { LightningElement,track} from 'lwc';

export default class PrivateComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track reactivePrivateProperty;
    nonReactivePrivateProperty;

    changeHandler1(event)
    {
        this.reactivePrivateProperty= event.target.value;
    }

    changeHandler2(event)
    {
        this.nonReactivePrivateProperty=event.target.value;
    }

}
```

[3] css code

```css
table tr td{
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[4] xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="privateComponent">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[5]Image  is attached  : SFDC UI [image]

Comment: All the class attributes are track. track decorator used only for non primitive data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields in a Lightning web component class are reactive from Spring ’20.
Refer [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm)

Comment: Just Reconfirming So no more  non reactive components

Comment: yes, for primitive data types (String, Number, and Boolean). However, for Composite 
 data types like Array, the elements are reactive only if  @track is used.